# Jenkins: Server SSL certificate verification failed - issuer is not trusted

Tags: svn, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am working with Jenkins to auto build. I call a batch file in jenkins:

**call Setup_trunk_01.bat**

The code of Setup_trunk_01.bat is:

```
svn propset svn:externals "https://svn02/vc/disney_kingdom_iphone/branches/maintenance/update12_gungho@90987 trunk" .
svn update .
```

and I have the error: `svn: E230001: Server SSL certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted`

When I call it manually, it works. But I can't change the code of Setup_trunk_01.bat. I think the problem is in the credentials. But I don't know what exactly error to fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess that your SVN server has is using self-signed SSL certificate for HTTPS. You should contact the system administrator and ask him to apply a valid server certificate that's signed by a trusted certificate authority.

You can also make SVN client ignore this certificate warning by adding [`--trust-server-cert`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.trust_server_cert) command line option to your command. BTW, don't forget to add [`--non-interactive`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.non_interactive) option to your commands, too.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use self-signed certificates: SSH on the Jenkins server and execute once on the command line:

```
svn list <REPO> --config-dir /var/lib/jenkins/.subversion/
```

Accept the self-signed certificate permanently. That's it. `--config-dir` should point to the .subversion folder of the Jenkins instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows,

1. Go to the "Services"
2. Select your jenkins service than right clik and select "Properties"
   [service properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIf12.png)
3. Select "Log On" tab.
4. Select "This account" choice
5. "Browse" your account and enter the password to "Password" field and confirm that.
6. Restart your jenkins servise

It worked for me